# NodeJS routing goes to '/' for defined page

Tags: node.js

I have defined routes in my node app as;

```
app.get('/welcome',welcome);
app.get('/allusers', allusers);
app.get('/', index);
```

The strange behavior is that when i type url to my browser **'/welcome'** it correctly works, but when i type **'allusers'** it will go to **'/'** route. When i change the name '**allusers'** to something like '**allusers1'** it works for the first time i ran the app but then the same behaviour happens. Am i missing something? Why does this strange behavior happens?

How i define the all users;

```
module.exports = function (app, myLocalize, functions, con, router) {
app.get('/allusers', function (req, res) {
    functions.setLocale(req, res, null);
    sess = req.session;
    if(sess && sess.user){
        con.query("select * from users", function (err, result, fields){
            if(err) throw err;
            var usersDb = result;
            res.render('allusers', 
            { 
                data: req.body,
                title: myLocalize.translate("SENTESBIR Report Automation"),
                templates: myLocalize.translate("Templates"), 
                rows: myLocalize.translate("Rows"), 
                users: myLocalize.translate("Users"), 
                reports: myLocalize.translate("Reports"), 
                columns : myLocalize.translate("Columns"),
                logout: myLocalize.translate("Logout"),
                analyses: myLocalize.translate("Analyses"),
                adminMenu: myLocalize.translate("Admin Menu"),
                chefMenu: myLocalize.translate("Chef Menu"),
                operatorMenu: myLocalize.translate("Operator Menu"),
                analysis: myLocalize.translate("Analysis"),
                logout: myLocalize.translate("Logout"),
                userName : functions.capitalizeFirstLetter(sess.user.firstname),
                userSurname : functions.capitalizeFirstLetter(sess.user.lastname),
                isAdmin : sess.user.isadmin,
                isChef : sess.user.ischef,
                isOperator : sess.user.isoperator,
                aboutUsTitle : myLocalize.translate("SENTESBIR is a provider of innovative solutions to joining and wear problems"),
                aboutUsWhatWeAreAbout : myLocalize.translate("What We're About?"),
                aboutUsWhatWeAreAboutText : myLocalize.translate("SENTESBIR is a provider of innovative solutions to joining and wear problems. We have extensive materials know-how, along with comprehensive knowledge of a wide range of applications. The result is an unparalleled capability to select the most appropriate solution to meet our customers' needs."),
                aboutUsWhatWeDo : myLocalize.translate("What We Do?"),
                aboutUsWhatWeDoText : myLocalize.translate("Our unique ability to integrate manufacturing processes, combined with our advanced problem-solving skills, enables us to create total solutions ranging from customized alloys to full assembly of complete components and the design of application equipment. SENTESBIR's quality assurance and production control programs meet the most demanding industry specifications."),
                name : myLocalize.translate("Name"),
                surname : myLocalize.translate("Surname"),
                isOperator : myLocalize.translate("Is Operator"),
                isAdmin : myLocalize.translate("Is Admin"),
                isChef : myLocalize.translate("Is Chef"),
                yes : myLocalize.translate("Yes"),
                no : myLocalize.translate("No"),
                email : myLocalize.translate("E-Mail"),
                usersDb : usersDb
            });
        });
    }else{
        res.redirect('/');
    }
});
return module;}
```

How i call it in app.js

```
var users = require('./pages/allusers.js')(app, localization.myLocalize, functions, db.con, router);
```

My route definition order;

```
var users = require('./pages/allusers.js')(app, localization.myLocalize, functions, db.con, router);
var main = require('./pages/welcome.js')(app, localization.myLocalize, functions, db.con, router);
var logout = require('./pages/logout.js')(app, localization.myLocalize, functions, db.con, router);
var login = require('./pages/login.js')(app, localization.myLocalize, functions, db.con, router);
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.redirect('/login');
});
```

I have Add the below code to get all routes

```
app._router.stack.forEach(function(r){
    if (r.route && r.route.path){
    console.log(r.route.path + " " + r.route.stack[0].method)
  }});
```

And the result is :

/allusers get

/welcome get

/logout get

/login get

/login post

/ get

Comment: Not enough code given to reproduce the problem. Do you have any middleware that runs any regex to match routes?

Comment: `app.get('/allusers' allusers);` should be `app.get('/allusers', allusers);` comma missing

Comment: the code is too long and confusing, so i have shortened it. Sorry for the mistake, actual code is app.get('/allusers', function (req, res) { ..... like this. I don't use any middleware. Only express.

Comment: Please add the statement in which you declared `allusers`. Maybe you did `require` the wrong route in that statement

Comment: The weird thing is i ran the application and login. Click on the url link and it seems to work fine. I stop the application and re-run it. Now if i type route it still works fine, after i login and click on the url link now it goes to '/' page. I have some redirects in my applications can that be the issue? should i provide the full code?

Comment: print the value of sess.user, also the condition value and check

Comment: the debugger never falls into allusers function so can't print the value of sess.user

Comment: Are you sure you have defined the /allusers route before the / route?

Comment: I have provided my route definitions too

Answer (score 0):

I have change "/allusers" to "/qaallusers" and now it is working as expected. I have no idea what happened. Maybe express routing is ordering them alphabetically and "/" was breaking something is my closest guess. Maybe it is a bug in express. Anyway the problem seems to be resolved for now.

Comment: I'm going to state that it's not a bug in Express, it's a bug in your code. For instance, looking at it, you have a _global_ (or rather: undeclared) variable `sess` that gets overwritten for each request (there's a hint in the observed behaviour: the route handler for `/allusers` _redirects to `/`_ if `sess && sess.user` is false). Also, `functions.setLocale(req, res, null)` looks like it doesn't work well with concurrent requests either.

Comment: i'm using visual code for debugging and debugger never falls in to my method so the sess variable is irrelevant, also there is another route with the same exact code but different page which seems to be working fine. I have only changed 'allusers' to 'qaallusers' and now it seems to work fine. setLocale function only puts a cookie for the user.

Comment: Unexpected behaviour in Express is, in my experience, _always_ caused by programmer error, not by bugs in Express.

Comment: I can't figure out what i am doing wrong. I have been looking at this and reading all types of forums for the last 2 days. I agree that it is most likely my fault.

Comment: Start by making sure that all variables (like `sess`) are properly declared (using `let`, `const` or `var` in front of it).

Comment: I'll re-visit my code. Thanks for the advice robert.